# QuickFix Market Data Incremental Tag repeating

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using quick fix. Once I send the market data message, the data coming in has the tag 268 as 2, which means it has two messages. But my fix application throws error as tag 278 appears more than once. So any idea how I can fix this?
Below is the DictinaryData:

```
<message name="MarketDataIncrementalRefresh" msgtype="X" msgcat="app">
<field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
<group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
  <field name="MDUpdateAction" required="Y" />
  <field name="DeleteReason" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryType" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryID" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryRefID" required="N" />
  <component name="Instrument" required="N" />
  <group name="NoUnderlyings" required="N">
    <component name="UnderlyingInstrument" required="N" />
  </group>
  <group name="NoLegs" required="N">
    <component name="InstrumentLeg" required="N" />
  </group>
  <field name="FinancialStatus" required="N" />
  <field name="CorporateAction" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryPx" required="N" />
  <field name="Currency" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntrySize" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryDate" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryTime" required="N" />
  <field name="TickDirection" required="N" />
  <field name="MDMkt" required="N" />
  <field name="TradingSessionID" required="N" />
  <field name="TradingSessionSubID" required="N" />
  <field name="QuoteCondition" required="N" />
  <field name="TradeCondition" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryOriginator" required="N" />
  <field name="LocationID" required="N" />
  <field name="DeskID" required="N" />
  <field name="OpenCloseSettlFlag" required="N" />
  <field name="TimeInForce" required="N" />
  <field name="ExpireDate" required="N" />
  <field name="ExpireTime" required="N" />
  <field name="MinQty" required="N" />
  <field name="ExecInst" required="N" />
  <field name="SellerDays" required="N" />
  <field name="OrderID" required="N" />
  <field name="QuoteEntryID" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryBuyer" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntrySeller" required="N" />
  <field name="NumberOfOrders" required="N" />
  <field name="MDEntryPositionNo" required="N" />
  <field name="Scope" required="N" />
  <field name="PriceDelta" required="N" />
  <field name="NetChgPrevDay" required="N" />
  <field name="Text" required="N" />
  <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N" />
  <field name="EncodedText" required="N" />
</group>
<field name="ApplQueueDepth" required="N" />
<field name="ApplQueueResolution" required="N" />
```

And these are the error message im getting.

```
20160623-17:28:44.915 : 8=FIX.4.49=21935=W34=3349=CfhDemoPrices52=20160623-17:28:45.82356=PrimoDEMOFIX55=GBPUSD262=PrimoApp123268=2269=0270=1.48205271=1000000290=164=20160627278=30/26-124551269=1270=1.48227271=1000000290=1278=30/26-12455610=066
20160623-17:28:44.930 : 8=FIX.4.49=12635=334=3449=PrimoDEMOFIX52=20160623-17:28:44.93056=CfhDemoPrices45=3358=Tag appears more than once371=278372=W373=1310=132
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how to decipher errors.

> 58=Tag appears more than once 371=278

This clearly mentions what the error is. 278 is present more than once in your FIX message. You have constructed the message erroneously.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the error message is coming from them, my application is the one which sends the reject message to the client. The tag 268 states it is a 2 group message. But my fix application is not considering it as repeated group. I think i need to change some entries in my DataDictionary, but not sure what or where to do that change.